# jquery hoover same class target only one

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jquery code in a page with a list of products for displaying two links when the user hover an item. The problem is all the products have the same class ".prod_box" and if I hover one item the script target all the div-s with the same class. Is it possible for the script to target only the item I'm hovering, not all the items that have the same class? Without giving each product a diferent class.

```
   $('.prod_box').mouseover(function () {
        $('.div_overlay').show();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('.div_overlay').hide();
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
            <div class="prod_box">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="prod_img">
                        <img src="images/produse_1.png" />
                        <div class="div_overlay">
                            <a href="http://google.ro" class="insider_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white_prod"></span></a>
                            <a href="http://google.ro" class="insider_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link white_prod"></span></a>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="title_produs text-left">
                        <h3>Nume produs</h3>
                        <p>Loreum ipsum situm dolores</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

           <div class="prod_box">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="prod_img">
                        <img src="images/produse_4.png" />
                        <div class="div_overlay">
                            <a href="http://google.ro" class="insider_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white_prod"></span></a>
                            <a href="http://google.ro" class="insider_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link white_prod"></span></a>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="title_produs text-left">
                        <h3>Nume produs</h3>
                        <p>Loreum ipsum situm dolores</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `.div_overlay` is a descendant element of `.prod_box`, you can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.prod_box').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.div_overlay').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find('.div_overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: Never understood what .find() does until now. It's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for:

```
$('.prod_box').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.div_overlay').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.div_overlay').hide();
});
```